# Ionic 2 - Proper way to show video

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Is there a proper way of including videos in the ionic pages? Because when I use the html 5 video element the buttons are not usable when fullscreen.

```
<video id="video1" width="100%" preload="metadata" controls webkit-playsinline>
      <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"/>
      <source type="video/ogg" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg"/>
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Is there any proper way of including videos in ionic2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as shown below.

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
  <video controls="controls" preload="metadata" autoplay="autoplay" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" class="videoPlayer">
   <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</ion-content>
```

[**Working Code Pen sample**](https://codepen.io/perrygovier/pen/cazjd?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `file-opener2` plugin which allow you to open any kind of files in the default applications on the device, check the usage https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener/
but make sure that you have installed `@ionic-native/core`

Comment: npm install @ionic-native/core@3.5.0 ? That one is invalid

Comment: You don't have to specify any version just hit this command to install the latest version  "npm install @ionic-native/core --save"

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use Video Player from Ionic Native?

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/video-player/

Comment: `Failed to navigate:  No provider for VideoPlayer!` followed by this one: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for VideoPlayer!
Error`

Comment: I put it in my app.module.ts but now it logs that video completed but it never played

Comment: Did you add it do the providers array?

Comment: Yes i did it but it is not playing video it only does that console log